# Average and group by query ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have some data in elasticsearch where for same value of time there are different speed values (there are seconds and millisecond fields). I want to group by the seconds and fetch average speed for that second. In short looking out for a es query like :

```
select average(speed) as speed, sec from index group by sec order by sec asc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `seconds` field and then an [`avg` metric sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html) on the `speed` field, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
  },
  "aggs": {
    "seconds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "seconds"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "speed": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "speed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yep, its works, just had to add size also as it was considering only 10 records for grouping and aggregate. Thanks a lot..